# Value of object inside json object is not evaluating in nested ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs

My app has a web service that returns the following json array

```
[{"id":1,"title":"Jeans #1","description":"Jeans Description Of Jeans #1","gender":1,"waists":[{"id":1,"sizeString":"28","enabled":true,"gender":1},{"id":3,"sizeString":"30","enabled":true,"gender":1}],"inseams":[{"id":1,"sizeString":"28","enabled":true,"gender":1},{"id":2,"sizeString":"29","enabled":true,"gender":1}],"style":{"id":1,"styleName":"Style #1","enabled":true,"gender":1},"ctr":0,"colorAndPatterns":[{"id":2,"description":"Green","background":"#00FF00","enabled":true,"gender":1},{"id":1,"description":"Red","background":"#FF0000","enabled":true,"gender":1}],"productOverviews":[{"id":3,"description":"Straight leg","enabled":true,"gender":1},{"id":1,"description":"Slim through thigh","enabled":true,"gender":1}],"enabled":true,"firstJeansImagesBycolor":[{"id":2,"colorAndPatternId":2,"enabled":true},{"id":6,"colorAndPatternId":1,"enabled":true}],"allJeansImagesByColor":[{"id":1,"colorAndPatternId":2,"enabled":true},{"id":2,"colorAndPatternId":2,"enabled":true},{"id":3,"colorAndPatternId":2,"enabled":true},{"id":4,"colorAndPatternId":2,"enabled":true},{"id":5,"colorAndPatternId":1,"enabled":true},{"id":6,"colorAndPatternId":1,"enabled":true},{"id":7,"colorAndPatternId":1,"enabled":true},{"id":8,"colorAndPatternId":1,"enabled":true}]}]
```

I am using angular's ng-repeat directive to iterate through the json array in the following manner

```
                 <div  ng-repeat="jean in currentJeans">
                    <div class="col-xs-4 jeans-listing at-repeat-twirl-in at-repeat-twirl-out" ng-repeat="colors in jean.colorAndPatterns | filter:{id:currentColorId}">

                        <a href="#/jeans-details/{{jean.id}}" class="thumbnail">
                            <img ng-src="static/images/jeans/{{jean.id}}/{{colors.id}}/{{jean.firstJeansImagesBycolor[$index].id}}.jpg" alt="Jeans Image"/>



                            <div class="caption">


                                <h5 class="text-center">{{jean.title}}</h5>


                            </div>
                            <button class="btn btn-default btn-sm" style="position: absolute;top:100px;left:30%;display:none;color:white;background-color:rgba(0,0,0,0.4)"><i class="fa fa-search"></i> Quick View</button>
                        </a>

                    </div>
                </div>
```

The problem i 'm facing is this expression evaluates to nothing

```
{{jean.firstJeansImagesBycolor[$index].id}}
```

Is this the right way to access arrays inside json objects or not what i 'm doing wrong ??

Here is the link to [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ykcLco6g/)

Comment: Can you create a jsfiddle? Everything looks fine, so for all we can see it could be a problem with the controller.

Comment: every ng-repeat creates its own scope, try debugging the $index first

Comment: Please format the JSON so we can actually read it.

Comment: Can you share a jsfiddle for this

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/ykcLco6g/

Comment: I think the problem here is that you're not using a controller, binding to $scope or even including the angular.js library, sorry to say (in the jsfiddle, that is)

Comment: $index value seems to be working fine it prints 0 & 1 so it belongs to the inner ng-repeat itself

Answer (score 0):

It is working perfectly fine. I just printed the path given and it prints:

http://jsfiddle.net/pfgkna8k/3/

```
<div ng-app="lists">
    <div ng-controller="ProductList">
           <div  ng-repeat="jean in currentJeans">
                    <div class="col-xs-4 jeans-listing at-repeat-twirl-in at-repeat-twirl-out" ng-repeat="colors in jean.colorAndPatterns | filter:{id:currentColorId}">

                        <a href="#/jeans-details/{{jean.id}}" class="thumbnail">
                            <img ng-src="static/images/jeans/{{jean.id}}/{{colors.id}}/{{jean.firstJeansImagesBycolor[$index].id}}.jpg" alt="Jeans Image"/>
                            static/images/jeans/{{jean.id}}/{{colors.id}}/{{jean.firstJeansImagesBycolor[$index].id}}.jpg



                            <div class="caption">


                                <h5 class="text-center">{{jean.title}}</h5>


                            </div>
                            <button class="btn btn-default btn-sm" style="position: absolute;top:100px;left:30%;display:none;color:white;background-color:rgba(0,0,0,0.4)"><i class="fa fa-search"></i> Quick View</button>
                        </a>

                    </div>
                </div>
    </div>
</div>
```